# Subscribing sequentially to a variable number of Observables in Angular 2+

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

Sorry if this was answered elsewhere, I tried to search but I'm not even sure what I'm looking for.

Let say I have this object to work with:

```
userRequest: {
    id: number,
    subject: string,
    ...
    orderIds: number[]
    ...
}

order: {
    id: number,
    ...
    clientId: number,
    productIds: number[]
}

client: {
    id: number,
    name: string,
    ...
}

product: {
    id: number,
    name: string,
    price: number
}
```

Now, at some point the user will fill a form using that composite object and send it for analysis. But before sending it, it has first to be validated. And I cannot validate in the form because the user is simply entering the data received on paper. If the data is "invalid", a request for more information will be sent.

So, I need to validate the request, but also the order, the products and the client. I am requested to show a "Validating Request" screen and after each element was checked, a "Valid" or "Invalid" screen. Simple enough.

But now, I'm sending http requests and get Observables to deal with. I'm trying to learn more about them and all the available operators and how to mix them, but at the moment, I'm completely lost.

So, I first get an `Observable<userRequest>` from server. Then, once I get a userRequest, I need to get all the orders from their id's, and when I get an "order", I have to get the client & his products.

All this is done asynchronously, but I cannot get the client or the products until I receive the order, and I need the userRequest to provide the orders. In addition, when I get an order, I need to get both the client AND the products at the "same time" since they both need the same order...? For the grand finale, for every element I get (request, order, client, product) I need to validate it and wait for every element to say "the request is valid" or not.

So to resume:

1. I need to get an `Observable<userRequest>` and validate
2. Now, I have to get an `Observable<order[]>` and validate each order
3. For each order, I have to 1) get an `Observable<Client>` and validate PLUS 2) get an `Observable<Product[]>` and validate each one
4. Wait for every observables to complete and check if it's valid or not

Steps 1 and 2 needs to be executed sequentially, but when step 2 completes, I need to execute steps 3.1 and 3.2 for each result of step 2. And wait.

I'm sure it's far from clear, I just hope it clear enough so you guys gets want I want to achieve. If you have any hints for me, please do share!!! ; )

### Edit

I do know somehow what needs to be done. But where I lose my cool, is when I need to chain the Observables sequentially (as each one depends on the one before), at various point I need to call a validation method and when it comes to the Client and the Products, both need the Order for it's Id. I did try many, many ways but I just don't grasp the concept completely.

bygrace - No, I don't want the validation to block. It should validate everything as it will result in a request for all the missing or invalid parts, and it should be showed at the end. That why I need a way to know when everything is done so I can check if errors were found.

The request, orders, client and products each comes from their respective services. The service makes an http resquest and returns an Observable. So I need to chain the calls (and when it comes to the Order, I need to get TWO Observables for the same Order Id).

QuietOran - Here's something I tried. It's horrible I know, but I'm so lost right now...

```
onValidateRequest(requestId: number) {

  this.requestService.getUserRequest$(this.requestId)
    .do(request => {
      this.validateRequest(request);
    })
    .concatMap(request => this.orderService.getOrdersForRequest$(request.id))
    .do(orders => {
      this.validateOrders(orders);
    })
    .concatMap(orders => {

      // Now, this is were I'm completely lost
      // I manage to get the request and the orders, but in this block, I need to get the client AND the products
      // and validate each one as I receive it
      // Then return something

    })
    .do(() => {
      // when I validate an element, if there's an error, I simple add it in an array. 
      // So when ALL the Observable above are completed, this function simply checks
      // if there's something in it
      this.checkForErrors();
    })
    .subscribe();
```

}

Comment: You seem to have a grasp on what needs to be done. Have you tried doing any of it? Do you have any code to share?

Comment: Do you want validation to block getting the next set of data (e.g. if `userRequest` is invalid then don't fetch its orders?). If not, do you want to show validation results as the stream processes or just at the end?

Comment: How do you get orders, products, and clients? Do you have to make separate requests for each order or do you pass the user request id or the list of order ids or something else?

Comment: Edited my question to provide you guys with more informations. Thanks for your time, it's really appreciated

Comment: Looks ok so far. Don't get bogged down by the best way to do it, initially just get it working. Obviously next you need to iterate the orders? Also, `Then return something`? That's not good - you should be clear what you need out from the start.

Comment: By return something, I'm sorry. It's not really the way I wanted to express myself. I mean, once I have my 'Orders', I'll need to iterate over them and call a variable number of Observable depending on the number of products and the client. But, how to accomplish that? And when it's done, shouldn't I have to return an Observable to subscribe to?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to give you something rough that you can refine with feedback because I'm not clear on the final shape of the data you want back and all. Hopefully this points you in the right direction.

Basically if you want the data from one observable to feed another then you can use `switchmap` or one of its cousins. If you need the value fed in as well as the result then just lump them together with a `combineLatest` or something similar.

```js
console.clear();
function getUserRequest(requestId) {
  return Rx.Observable.of({ id: 1, subject: 'a', orderIds: [10, 20] })
   .delay(500).take(1);
}
function getOrdersForRequest(requestId) {
  return Rx.Observable.of([
    { id: 10, clientId: 100, productIds: [ 1000 ] },
    { id: 20, clientId: 200, productIds: [ 1001, 1002 ] }
  ]).delay(200).take(1);
}
function getClientForOrder(orderId) {
  let client;
  switch(orderId) {
    case 10:
      client = { id: 100, name: 'Bob' };
      break;
    case 20:
      client = { id: 200, name: 'Alice' };
      break;
  }
  return Rx.Observable.of(client).delay(200).take(1);
}
function getProductsForOrder(orderId) {
  let products;
  switch(orderId) {
    case 10:
      products = [{ id: 1000, name: 'p1', price: 1 }];
      break;
    case 20:
      products = [
        { id: 1001, name: 'p1', price: 2 },
       { id: 1002, name: 'p1', price: 3 }
      ];
      break;
  }
  return Rx.Observable.of(products).delay(200).take(1);
}

Rx.Observable.of(1)
  .switchMap(id => Rx.Observable.combineLatest(
    getUserRequest(id),
    getOrdersForRequest(id)
      .switchMap(orders => Rx.Observable.combineLatest(
          Rx.Observable.of(orders),
          Rx.Observable.combineLatest(...orders.map(o => getClientForOrder(o.id))),
          Rx.Observable.combineLatest(...orders.map(o => getProductsForOrder(o.id)))
        )
      ),
    (userRequest, [orders, clients, products]) =>
        ({ userRequest, orders, clients, products })
  )
).subscribe(x => { console.dir(x); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.6/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Right now I flattened the results by category. You may want them nested or something like that. This is just a rough pass so provide feedback as needed.